# Integrating LinkedinAPI with Spring Security OAuth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am in a very weird problem, most probably caused by linkedin API. I have configured linkedin as a provider, as normally as anyone can. PFA Snippets.

Problem is very weird:
For me to get user's information from endpoint, I need `openid` in scope. Now, even though scope is `openid`, linkedin returns an opaque token and doesn't provide JWKs URI.

By looking `openid` in scope, spring's [OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/26372aaad11e35f98e9240e6b8b683b8caebc25c/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/authentication/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java#L98) rejects it and asks [OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/26372aaad11e35f98e9240e6b8b683b8caebc25c/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/oidc/authentication/OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java#L156) (See line where it calls `createOidcToken` which internally looks for JWKs URI) Problem is, Linkedin doesn't return a JWT in the first place.

**Important Note: I have tried keeping openid scope initially and removing in debug point so that OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider accepts it, and it works.**

I am trying to create my CustomAuthenticationProvider, but Spring is failing to inject dependencies.

********FILES*********

***application.yml***

```
 spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          linkedin:
            provider: linkedin
            client-id: ${LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET}
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_post
            authorization-grant-type: 'authorization_code'
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/linkedin'
            scope:
              - profile
              - email
              - openid
        provider:
          linkedin:
            authorization-uri: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
            token-uri: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
            user-info-uri: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
```

***Config File***

```
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public  SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/resources/**", "/logout")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauthLoginConfig -> oauthLoginConfig
                        .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpointConfig -> {
                            tokenEndpointConfig.accessTokenResponseClient(linkedinTokenResponseClient());
                        }));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }


private static DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient linkedinTokenResponseClient() {
        var defaultMapConverter = new DefaultMapOAuth2AccessTokenResponseConverter();
        Converter<Map<String, Object>, OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> linkedinMapConverter = tokenResponse -> {
            var withTokenType = new HashMap<>(tokenResponse);
            withTokenType.put(OAuth2ParameterNames.TOKEN_TYPE, OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER.getValue());
            return defaultMapConverter.convert(withTokenType);
        };

        var httpConverter = new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();
        httpConverter.setAccessTokenResponseConverter(linkedinMapConverter);

        var restOperations = new RestTemplate(List.of(new FormHttpMessageConverter(), httpConverter));
        restOperations.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());
        var client = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
        client.setRestOperations(restOperations);
        return client;
    }
```

***CustomAuthenticationProvider***

Copied as it is from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/26372aaad11e35f98e9240e6b8b683b8caebc25c/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/authentication/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java#L98) Except, deleted line 98 to 105.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: keep Spring defaults and, on clients, read only ID-tokens (or user info with non-OpenID providers). A client should use access tokens for no more than authorizing requests to resource servers (it should not try to parse it).

`openid` scope asks an OpenID Provider to return a **ID-token**, which, as per OpenID spec, must be a JWT. But this spec puts absolutely no constraints on the access tokens format. It is very likely that LinkedIn intends to restrict the usage of access tokens it emits to its own API (you can use it as an identity source for your own authorization server, not as a free authorization server for your resource servers).

Comment: Yes exactly, actually linkedin WAS sending openid token as JWT all along and it makes my issue obsolete, all I had to do is disable "Nonce" since linkedin doesn't support it and I was good to go! For people who are facing same issue, I am posting  how I removed nonce as an answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Actually linkedin **DOES SEND** *id_token (open id token)* as JWT.

I was getting error because once it parses JWT, next thing it does is verifies Nonce which LinkedIn does not support. That's where error was coming from.

So to prevent that, ***remove Nonce from request*** and spring will understand that you don't want nonce verification.

```
public  SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/resources/**", "/logout")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauthLoginConfig -> oauthLoginConfig
                        .authorizationEndpoint((authorizationEndpointConfig ->
                                authorizationEndpointConfig.authorizationRequestResolver(
                                        requestResolver(this.clientRegistrationRepository) // See this.
                                ))
                        )
                        .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpointConfig -> tokenEndpointConfig
                                .accessTokenResponseClient(linkedinTokenResponseClient())
                        )
                );
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

private static DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver requestResolver
            (ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver requestResolver =
                new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository,
                        "/oauth2/authorization");
        requestResolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(c ->
                c.attributes(stringObjectMap -> stringObjectMap.remove(OidcParameterNames.NONCE))
                        .parameters(params -> params.remove(OidcParameterNames.NONCE))
        );

        return requestResolver;
    }
```